# How to convert curl data-binary into HTTP body in react native fetch?

Tags: react-native, http

I'm able to get results via `curl -X POST -u "apikey:x" --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary @/Users/xx/Downloads/audio-file.flac  "https://apixxx"`.

But in react native below would give error "400  Bad Request error: Stream was 36 bytes but needs to be at least 100 bytes." --apparently it took the "body" I put as a string not a binary. How to fix it please? Thanks!

```
 window.btoa = require('Base64').btoa;
    let result = await fetch(
      'https://apixxx' , {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'audio/flac',
          'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa(`apikey:x`)
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'data-binary': '@./audio-file.flac',
        }),
      }
    ).then(response => response.json());
```

I then tried another version with formdata, gives error: "Bad Request", code: 400, error: "No JSON object could be decoded"

```
    window.btoa = require('Base64').btoa;
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('file', {
        uri: `file://${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/audio-file.flac`,
        name: 'audio-file.flac',
        type: 'audio/flac',
      })
        let res = await fetch('https://apixxx', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
              'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa(`apikey:x`),
            },
            body: formData,
          }).then(response => console.log(response.json()));
```

How to fix it please? Thanks!

Comment: Do you remember the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

the `body` part is incorrect, it must be kind of binary data, not a string/json/object. For example:

```
let blobData = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'})
const result = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: blobData
})
```

if you wanna POST your local file => get its binary data by replacing the `blobData` line with

```
const response = await fetch(your_file_path);
const blobData = await response.blob();
```